# Finding a solution to $\frac{dy}{dx}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find a solution to $\frac{dy}{dx} = xy+7x+3y+21$

First step, i believe is to factor the right side, and make it $(x+3)(y+7)$

thus, $\frac{dy}{dx} = (x+3)(y+7)$ and if I move all $y$'s to the left, and $x$'s to the right, I have, $\frac{\frac{dy}{dx}}{y+7} = x+3$ but how do I approach further?

Apparently, the answer is $y=\exp\left(3x+ \frac{x^2}{2}\right)-7$. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: You were doing great! You have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{y+7} = \int (x+3)~ dx$. Solve the integration on each side and simplify to solve for $y(x)$.

Comment: Note that the solution you quote corresponds to the particular solution that has $y(0) = -6$. In general there should be a free constant $c$ in front of the $\exp$ (which will arise as an integration constant when you derive the solution).

Comment: @Moo (cont.) This is what is called a _separable_ differential equation, when you can get it on the form $$f(y)\frac{dy}{dx}=g(x)$$ Such an equation is solved by integrating on both sides with respect to $x$, and noting that you have $\frac{dy}{dx}dx=dy$ on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have $\displaystyle \int \dfrac{dy}{y+7} = \int (x+3) dx$

Let $u=y+7$ and $du=dy$. This sets up the LHS for a natural logarithm. The RHS can be integrated via the power rule. So we have $\ln |y+7|=\frac{x^2}{2}+3x+C$. Can you solve for the form that you gave as the answer?